# Textbox value without Javascript

Tags: html, css

Is there any option without Javascript to put a disappeared value on textbox

Comment: What do you mean by "disappeared value"?

Comment: Do you mean something like the HTML5 placeholder? Example here: http://davidwalsh.name/dw-content/html5-placeholder.php

Explained here: http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder

Comment: Yes I am looking for that actually. Thank you Michal B.

Comment: I meant disapeared value as the value will go on click of the box

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though your question is not clear but I think the following code may help you.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="test">
```

But remember Placeholder is not supported by below IE9 as it is the code of html5.

Comment: Thanks Jhilom. It helped. I am using IE9.